# Re-export Flow named interfaces exports from multiple files in folder index

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a `interfaces` folder with different files containing one or more Flow interfaces.

I would like to export all my interfaces from an `index.js` file, like so:

`interfaces/index.js`

```js
/* @flow */

import type config from './config'

export default {
  ...config,
}
```

but Flow won't let me and returns this error:

```
Cannot reference type config [1] from a value position.Flow(InferError)
```

---

`interfaces/config.js`

```js
/* @flow */

export interface Config {
  smtp: {
    host: string,
    secure: boolean,
    port: number,
    auth: {
      user: string,
      pass: string,
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: boolean,
    },
  },
  company: Company,
}

export interface Company {
  name: string,
  phone: string,
  address: string,
  product: {
    name: string,
  },
}
```

---

Is there any way to achieve this ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `type` is not needed for import interfaces

Comment: @Alex actually it is, because without it the [flow-remove-types](https://github.com/facebookarchive/flow-remove-types) lib won't remove the line when stripping the code to be run on NodeJS ;)

Comment: hm, seems to a bit messy here https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4319

Comment: @Alex Flow is definitely messy for the moment

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution, I needed to use the `export type { ... } from '...'` syntax, as follows:

`interfaces/index.js`

```js
/* @flow */

export type * from './config'
```

Hope this can be useful to somebody else :)

Comment: As stated in the question: I have a interfaces folder with different files containing one or more Flow interfaces. I would like to export all my interfaces from an index.js file. (so I can import the entire folder)

Comment: so it was just `config` vs `Config`? You can also `export * from './config'`

Comment: "You can also export * from './config'" thanks for pointing out, working like a charm (with type) !